# Worksheet 1 paste value to Worksheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy-paste

I have a workbook for reports, I am looking to see if there is a way to take data from the worksheet(let's call it worksheet 1) and paste into another worksheet(let's call worksheet 2). I don't want the whole row copied just certain cells within a row pasted to certain cells within worksheet 2.

**Example:** worksheet 1, if cell $K12 Contains the text "TD","BH","HS","HSW","UHR"

```
Worksheet 1 $B12 paste value to Worksheet 2 $P12
Worksheet 1 $D12 paste value to Worksheet 2 $B12
Worksheet 1 $E12 paste value to Worksheet 2 $O12
Worksheet 1 $K12 paste value to Worksheet 2 $F12
Worksheet 1 $L12 paste value to Worksheet 2 $C12`
```

Comment: Does it need to contain all the text, or only one of the values mentioned?

Comment: All, or any of them?

Comment: the text will contain one of the values quoted